# testing const pointer nature of this pointer

Tags: c++

Since `this` pointer is a `const pointer` (not pointer to const) in a non-const member function (from **C++ Primer**), I tried to get an error message (on purpose) by assigning address of some other object to `this` but it is not an **lvalue** so it gave another error (which I didn't want).

And if I try assigning object to de-referenced `this` then it will be simply assigning one object to another.

Is there any way where I can test the `const pointer` nature of `this`

Answer (score 1):

I think the compiler has given you the correct error message. From the standard, [[class.this]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.this#1)

> In the body of a non-static ([class.mfct]) member function, the keyword `this` is a prvalue whose value is a pointer to the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of a class `X` is `X*`. If the member function is declared `const`, the type of `this` is `const X*`,

The standard doesn't say `this` is a `const` pointer; instead, it says the type of `this` is `X*` (or `const X*` in `const` member function). And `this` is a prvalue which can't be modified, as the error message said.

From the point view of preventing `this` from being modified (or taking its address), declaring it as a prvalue is enough. On the other hand, just declaring it as `const` is not enough because of the potential usage of `const_cast`.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus In `const` member function, it's pointer to `const`. Otherwise, it's pointer to non-`const`.

Comment: As this pointer points to the current object it makes sense that it cannot point to any other object except the current object hence shouldn't it be (at least) `const pointer` (irrespective of the const-ness of member function).

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus I get what you mean. Making it a prvalue has been enough to prevent it from being modified. On the other hand, just making it `const` is not enough because of `const_cast`.

Comment: There's more to it than that -- since `this` is a `prvalue` and not a `const lvalue`, you can't take its address with unary `&`.